# TUT language translator

Tags: code-golf, string

Text may be translated to a written version of [TUT language](http://www.tutlanguage.com/pages/amSpeech.html) by replacing each letter by the corresponding "TUT word", as given in the following table (adapted from the linked article)<sup>*</sup>:

```
a  e        h  hash     o  o        u  yu
b  bub      i  ay       p  pup      v  vuv
c  kut      j  jag      q  kwak     w  waks
d  dud      k  kak      r  rut      x  eks
e  i        l  lul      s  sus      y  yak
f  fuf      m  mum      t  tut      z  zuz
g  jug      n  nun            

* Exceptions: 
(1) Upper case letters have corresponding TUT words in upper case.
(2) A doubled letter becomes 'skwer' ('SKWER') followed by the TUT word for that letter.
    - An n-fold letter is treated as a number of doubles, followed by a single if needed.
    - To be considered a double or n-fold letter, the letters must be in the same case.
(3) 'rut' ('RUT') is replaced by 'rud' ('RUD') if immediately followed by 'dud' ('DUD').
```

Write a program with the following i/o behavior:

**Input** (from stdin): A binary (0/1) indicator *i* and an ASCII string *s*.

- If *i* = 0 then *s* may contain any ASCII text.
- If *i* = 1 then *s* must be the TUT Language output for some valid input.

**Output** (to stdout): A binary (0/1) indicator *j* and an ASCII string *t*.

- If *i* = 0 then *j* = 1 and *t* is the translation of *s* **to** TUT Language.
- If *i* = 1 then *j* = 0 and *t* is the translation of *s* **from** TUT Language.
- For any valid input, applying the program to its own output must exactly reproduce the original input; i.e., *program* (*program* (*i*, *s*)) = (*i*, *s*). Input and output must have exactly the same format.

**Scoring**: The score is the number of characters in the program -- lowest score wins.

**Examples**

[**(a)**](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yJzQiemCIuY)

```
(0, 'Look for the birds.')
(1, 'LULskwerokak fuforut tuthashi bubayruddudsus.')
```

[**(b)**](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tsAZ0RweVxk)

```
(0, '"Mrs. Hogwallop up and R-U-N-N-O-F-T."')
(1, '"MUMrutsus. HASHojugwakseskwerlulopup yupup enundud RUT-YU-NUN-NUN-O-FUF-TUT."')
```

(**c**)

```
(0, 'QWX WWW Rrrrd deeeeep')
(1, 'KWAKWAKSEKS SKWERWAKSWAKS RUTskwerrutruddud dudskweriskweriipup')
```

(**d**)

```
(0, 'aa AA aA Aa rd RD rD Rd')
(1, 'skwere SKWERE eE Ee ruddud RUDDUD rutDUD RUTdud)
```

(((Aside about pronunciation: The TUT words for the vowels (`e`, `i`, `ay`, `o`, `yu`) are supposed to represent the usual sounds of (a, e, i, o, u) when reciting the alphabet -- i.e., rhyming with (may, me, my, mow, mew). In the three-or-more-letter TUT words, the symbols (`u`,`a`,`e`) are supposed to sound as in (but, bat, bet) respectively -- these are ASCII replacements for (`ʌ` `æ` `ɛ`)  in the linked article.)))

Comment: do we have to support doubled uppercase? What's the tut translation of `AA`, `SKWERE` or `skwerE`? What about tripled letters? is it `wakswakswaks`, `skwerwakswaks`, `waksskwerwaks`, or even `kyubwaks`, or we may choose?

Comment: `rrd` should translate to `skwerruddud`; are we allowed to leave it at `skwerrutdud`?

Comment: @JanDvorak - Yes, it should handle doubled letters, regardless of case. Input (0,'AA SKWERE skwerE') should have output(1,'ee SUSKAKWAKSIRUTI suskakwaksirutI'). Inputs (1,'AA') and (1,'skwerE') are not valid because 'AA' and 'skwerE' do not occur as outputs of any valid input. Input (1, 'SKWERE') should have output (0,'EE'). A string of three or more letters should be regarded as some number of doubles, possibly followed by a single. Input (0,'rrd') should have output (1,'skwerruddud').

Comment: uh... how does `0,"AA"` translate to `1,"ee"`? As for `1,"SKWERE"`, I assume you meant `0,"AA"`, not `0,"EE"`.

Comment: @JanDvorak - Sorry, my bad: input (0,'AA SKWERE skwerE') should have output (1,'SKWERE SUSKAKWAKSIRUTI suskakwaksirutI'), and input (1, 'SKWERE') should have output (0,'AA'). I hope I got it right this time ... When I can manage to keep it straight myself, I'll edit the question :)

Comment: OK... is my answer correct, then? :-)

Comment: @JanDvorak -- See my reply to your answer.

Comment: Shouldn't `LULskwerokut` read `LULskwerokak` in the output of the first example?

Comment: @DavidCarraher -- Indeed it should; thanks ... fixing.

Comment: Heh, this question has more naughty Dutch words than usual :P

Comment: @r.e.s. I need 2 clarifications because I'm confused! `0,Rd` should return `1,RUTdud` or `1,RUDdud`? `0,AA` should return `1,skwerE` or `1,SKWERE`.

Comment: @psxls - I intended (0,rd_RD_rD_Rd) -> (1,ruddud_RUDDUD_rutDUD_RUTdud) and (0,aa_AA_aA_Aa) -> (1,skwere_SKWERE_eE_Ee). Rule (3) applies to the TUT words 'skwere' and "SKWERE'.

Comment: I reorganized the list of exceptions and added an example to clarify the above points.

Comment: In Polish, Skwer means square, place, usually green :)

Comment: this challenge kinda sus

Answer (score 6):

#### Ruby, <del>310</del> 311 characters

```
h=Hash[(?a..?z).zip %w{e bub kut dud i fuf jug hash ay jag kak lul mum nun o pup kwak rut sus tut yu vuv waks eks yak zuz}]
h["rd"]="ruddud"
h.keys.each{|k|h[k[0]+k]="skwer"+h[k]}
h.keys.each{|k|h[k.upcase]=h[k].upcase}
h=h.invert if b=getc==?1
i=gets
print b ?0:1;(k=i;k=k.chop until h[k]||!k[1];$><<(h[k]||k);i[k]="")until i==""
```

Correctly handles:

- squared uppercase (unfix by merging iterations gains 18 characters)

  - if `AA` should turn into `skwerE`, swap lines #3 and #4
  - I also assume `aA` and `Aa` should turn into `eE` and `Ee` respectively
- `rrd` translates to `skwerruddud (unfix gains 3 characters)
- in cubes the first pair is reported as a square. `rrrd` turns into `skwerrutruddud`. `rrrrd` becomes `skwerrutskwerruddud`
- the output is now a valid input. It is, indeed, required by the spec
- uses newline as input terminator

<del>Input requires there be no newline between the indicator and the string, output puts it there (fix: 1 character).</del> Console output suppressed at this point to prevent mixing with STDIN. Unfix free, it's just a little bit uglier.

Example input:

```
0Hello
```

Output:

```
1
HASHiskwerlulo
```

Comment: I was vacillating about whether to require input & output to have *identical* formats, but it wasn't clear in the question, so ... this answer looks fine to me (so far -- I'll run some tests on the answers soon).

Comment: I don't know why, but your program runs for me -- both [online](http://ideone.com/NDlSLL) and off -- only if `getc` is prefixed with `STDIN.` (six more characters).

Comment: I'm using jRuby IRB 1.7.5 (2.0.0) and it shows me only a warning. What verion are you using?

Comment: I like the shorthand to create the map. I just included it fully. Which makes it unlikely that I will beat that.

Comment: @r.e.s. I believe that the input/output requirement was clear: `For any valid input, applying the program to its own output must exactly reproduce the original input; i.e., program (program (i, s)) = (i, s).` But it would only cost 1 character to fix that.

Comment: Thanks Jan. My program could be 4 characters smaller if I don't add a newline. Wait. I can read a single character for the cost of 2 extra characters...

Comment: @JanDvorak - I'm using Ruby 1.9.3 from www.ruby-lang.org (as does Ideone.com). I suppose it's time to upgrade.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn - The question is whether "exactly reproduce" may in some degree refer to *content* rather than exclusively to *format*, and I gave Jan the benefit of the doubt over the presence/absence of a single newline.

Comment: The point is that the output should be a possible input format, so `cat input | prog | prog` should work at least.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn - Point taken. Apparently Jan agrees, since he revised his program accordingly. I will clarify this in the question.

Comment: Jan - you've revised your program, but not your example output (it still has the newline). Also, I just upgraded to Ruby 2.0.0, and still your program won't run for me unless `getc` is replaced with `STDIN.getc`. (I'm using `echo 0Hello | ruby tut.rb`.)

Comment: @JanDvorak Very nice +1. But it fails at `0Rd`.

Comment: @psxls Depends on the interpretation. If you say that it contains 2 rules or any combination of them.

Comment: @JanDvorak You was right, r.e.s. just [clarified](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/15301/tut-language-translator?noredirect=1#comment28467_15301) the situation. I'll have to change my own answer...!

Answer (score 3):

### Perl, <s>453</s> <s>443</s> <s>309</s> <s>307</s> <s>303</s> 299

```
($x,$_)=split//,<>,2;@x{a..z,rd}=(e,bub,kut,dud,i,fuf,jug,hash,ay,jag,kak,lul,mum,nun,o,pup,kwak,rut,sus,tut,yu,vuv,waks,eks,yak,zuz,ruddud);$x{$_ x2}=skwer.$x{$_}for a..z;$x{uc$_}=uc$x{$_}for keys%x;%x=reverse%x if$x;$z=join"|",sort{length$b<=>length$a}keys%x;s/\G(.*?)($z)/$1$x{$2}/g;print!$x+0,$_
```

**Test cases:**

I have tested successfully the (a),(b),(c) and (d) test cases provided in the OP.

**A *somewhat* more readable version:**

```
($x,$_)=split//,<>,2;
@x{a..z,rd}=(e,bub,kut,dud,i,fuf,jug,hash,ay,jag,kak,lul,mum,nun,o,pup,kwak,rut,sus,tut,yu,vuv,waks,eks,yak,zuz,ruddud);
$x{$_ x2}=skwer.$x{$_}for a..z;
$x{uc$_}=uc$x{$_}for keys%x;
%x=reverse%x if$x;
$z=join"|",sort{length$b<=>length$a}keys%x;
s/\G(.*?)($z)/$1$x{$2}/g;
print!$x+0,$_
```

Comment: Nice! Some good test cases to check, it appears I have a lot of work to do!
I've had a quick look at yours and I think you can knock a few bytes off using barewords instead of qw (change `qw(bub kut ... yak zuz)` to `(bub,kut ... yak,zuz)`), also you can replace `keys%x` with `@b` (since you know what the keys are because of `$x`). A small change to save another three is `$1eq uc($1)` to `uc$1eq$1`. You could also drop the `+` before the `!` of the print for that extra byte to take you to 443.
Hope that's all valid, I've tested limited test cases!

Comment: Hmmm, `uc$1eq$1` might have to be `uc$1 eq$1`, but I'm not certain... Sorry if that's wrong!

Comment: Thanks Dom for the tips! You saved me 10 chars. Still there's room for improvement, I'll get back to work.. :)

Answer (score 2):

### Tcl, <s>395</s> <s>394</s> 392

```
set m { rd ruddud a e h hash o o u yu b bub i ay p pup v vuv c kut j jag q kwak w waks d dud k kak r rut x eks e i l lul s sus y yak f fuf m mum t tut z zuz g jug n nun ঙ skwer}
set m $m[string tou $m]
if [read stdin 1] {puts 0[regsub -all ঙ(.) [string map [lreverse $m] [gets stdin]] {\1\1}]} {puts 1[string map $m [regsub -all (.)\\1 [gets stdin] ঙ\\1]]}
```

Notes:

- Uses `skwerruddud` for `rrd`.
- `skwereskweree` for `aaaaa`.

Example input:

```
0Hello
```

Output:

```
1HASHiskwerlulo
```

How it works:

- `m` is at the beginning a string.
- I concatiate it with the uppercase map.
- [string map] does most of the stuff for me (uses a list, so anything that is a valid list...)
- regexp for for the double characters. Use a special replacement character (`ঙ`).

Comment: The Bengali Abugida, how did you choose that character?

Comment: `\ufff` iirc. Doesn't really matter. Any non-ascii character would do.

Comment: It was `\u999`. As I said, the only important thing was: not an ascii character.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn it fails at example (c), returns `1KWAKWAKSEKS skwerWAKSWAKS RUTskwerrutruddud dudskweriskweriipup`.

Comment: @psxls Which is correct: ``A doubled letter is replaced by `skwer` followed by the TUT word for that letter.`` No mention of `SKWER`.

Answer (score 2):

### Perl 385

```perl
$t=e0bub0kut0dud0i0fuf0jug0hash0ay0jag0kak0lul0mum0nun0o0pup0kwak0rut0sus0tut0yu0vuv0waks0eks0yak0zuz;@t=split 0,$t."0\U$t";@s=(a..z,A..Z);while(<>){($-,$_)=split/ /,$_,2;@l{$-?@t:@s}=$-?@s:@t;if($-){for$@(@t){s/skwer$@/$@$@/gi}for$@(@t){s/$@/$l{$@}/g}s/(r)ud/$1/gi}else{s/(.)/$l{$1}||$1/ge;for$@(@t){$r=lc$@eq$@?"skwer":"SKWER";s/$@$@/$r$@/g}s/(ru)t(d)/$1$2$2/gi}$-=!$-;print"$- $_"}
```

Syntax highlighter hates this one...

Expects input on STDIN, format is `0 (or 1) String to convert here.`:

```perl
0 Hello! # input
1 HASHiskwerlulo! # output

1 HASHiskwerlulo!
0 Hello!

0 Look for the birds.
1 LULskwerokak fuforut tuthashi bubayruddudsus.

1 LULskwerokak fuforut tuthashi bubayruddudsus.
0 Look for the birds.

0 "Mrs. Hogwallop up and R-U-N-N-O-F-T."
1 "MUMrutsus. HASHojugwaksaskwerlulopup yupup anundud RUT-YU-NUN-NUN-O-FUF-TUT."

1 "MUMrutsus. HASHojugwaksaskwerlulopup yupup anundud RUT-YU-NUN-NUN-O-FUF-TUT."
0 "Mrs. Hogwallop up and R-U-N-N-O-F-T."
```

**Edit**: I've noticed an issue with the translation of X (it becomes 'aks' in the reversion, I'll look into this later. Might need to re-order the hash :(.

Comment: apart of X, it fails also in OP's examples (b), (c) and check also in my answer the test cases (e) & (g).

Comment: This is very true, back to the drawing board!

Answer (score 2):

### APL (Dyalog) (372)

You can really tell APL doesn't have built-in string handling functions (except for the generic array ones). I had to write my own `tolower` (it's `L`). As always with multiline Dyalog APL, to test it, paste it in an edit window and then call it (`T`).

```
T
Q←⎕UCS
L←{Q(Q⍵)+32×⍵∊⎕A}
Z←{⎕←⊃z,.⍺⍺1⌽z←⍵,' '}
w←L¨W←1↓¨W⊂⍨' '=W←' E BUB KUT DUD I FUF JUG HASH AY JAG KAK LUL MUM NUN O PUP KWAK RUT SUS TUT YU VUV WAKS EKS YAK ZUZ RUD SKWER'
⍞{⎕←~⍵:{U←L⍣(l←⍺∊L⎕A)
~l∨⍺∊⎕A:⍺
⍺=⍵:U⊃⌽W
'rd'≡L¨⍺⍵:U'RUD'
U⊃W[96-⍨Q+L⍺]}Z⍺
{'rR'∊⍨v←⊃⍺:v
(⊃⌽w)≡m←L⍺:⍵∇⍬
~w∊⍨⊂m:⍺
L⍣(⍺≡L⍺)⍨⎕A/⍨26↑≡∘m¨w}Z{~×⍴⍵:''
∨/H←⊃¨⍷∘(L⍵)¨w:(⊂l↑⍵),∇⍵↓⍨l←⍴⊃H/W
(⊂⊃⍵),∇1↓⍵}⍺}⎕
```

Usage:

```
      T
⎕:
0
"Mrs. Hogwallop up and R-U-N-N-O-F-T."     
1
"MUMrutsus. HASHojugwakseskwerlulopup yupup enundud RUT-YU-NUN-NUN-O-FUF-TUT."      
      T
⎕:
1
"MUMrutsus. HASHojugwakseskwerlulopup yupup enundud RUT-YU-NUN-NUN-O-FUF-TUT."      
0
"Mrs. Hogwallop up and R-U-N-N-O-F-T."
```

Answer (score 2):

### GNU Sed, 514

```
s/$/\n@a!e@b!bub@c!kut@d!dud@e!i@f!fuf@g!jug@h!hash@i!ay@k!kak@l!lul@m!mum@n!nun@o!o@p!pup@q!kwak@r!rud@r!rut@s!sus@t!tut@u!yu@v!vuv@w!waks@x!eks@y!yak@z!zuz/
s/.*\n\(.*\)/&\U\1@/
ta
:a
s/^1/0\v/
td
s/^0/1\v/
:t
/\v\n/bf
s/\v\([^a-z]\)/\1\v/i
tt
s/\v\([a-z]\)\1/skwer\v\1/
s/\v\([A-Z]\)\1/SKWER\v\1/
s/\v\(.*\)\(.*\n.*@\1!\(\w\+\)@\)/\3\v\2/
s/rut\vd/rud\vd/
s/RUT\vD/RUD\vD/
bt
:d
/\v\n/bf
s/\v\([^a-z]\)/\1\v/i
td
s/\v\(skwer\)/\1\v/i
s/\v\(.*\)\(.*\n.*@\(.\)!\1@\)/\3\v\2/
s/skwer\(.\)\v/\1\1\v/
bd
:f
s/\v.*//
```

Could probably be shortened, though I'm done for now.

Uses a lookup table to handle conversions in both directions, should handle all exceptions including skwer case and ruddud/RUDDUD correctly.

input taken on each line as 0/1 followed by the string. Uses `\v` (vertical tab) as a cursor.